# How to use both php and text in <a title link code?

Tags: php

Here's what I got so far:

```
<?php
//some other code
<a title="Get updates from 'echo get_the_author();'" href="' . esc_url($facebook_profile) . '"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

I'm trying to echo get_the_author(); in the a title=, but get nothing, 
what do I need to do to get it going?
Thanks,

Comment: See one of [your very own previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106631/how-can-i-append-this-php-link-to-the-end-of-the-excerpt/31107378#31107378) on how to switch between PHP statement context and literal HTML sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going about it wrong. Don't mix like that, rather do something like:

```
<a title="Get updates from <?php echo get_the_author(); ?>" href="<?php  esc_url($facebook_profile); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
```

If you're dead-set on using PHP to produce it, then you need to `echo` it out:

```
<?php

echo '<a title="Get updates from ' . get_the_author() . '" href="' . esc_url($facebook_profile) . '"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>';
```

Comment: Or use shorthand `<?= get_the_author(); ?>`

Comment: brilliant! I used: echo '<li class="facebook"><a title="Get updates from ' . get_the_author() . '" href="<?php  esc_url($facebook_profile); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>';

Comment: i wasn't adding the . after the php, (i only tried it before the php and gave up)